# ms-outlook://events/new URI scheme

Tags: ms-access, outlook, uri

I am trying to create an outlook calendar event and add participants using the ms-outlook URI scheme.

This is URI scheme : ms-outlook://events/new.

ms-outlook://events/new?title=MY%20MEETING&start=2019-01-29T13:00:00&end=2019-01-29T14:00:00&location=LOCATION&attendees=some.person@email.com

I tried this URI scheme but participants are not added. Please provide if any new URI scheme available. What parameter to use to add attendees/participants for new event?

I want to open native outlook app so that's why not using deeplink:
https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose